Clone soft and hardlinked folders to another drive

I have a /src on ZFS that consists of /src/backup/day1, /src/backup/day2, etc
Some files in day1 and day2 are hardlinked using rsync's --link-dest=...
I also have a remote EXT4 mounted as /dst using Samba
I would like to make a copy to /src into /dst while preserving these hardlinks, ideally, also on the basis of delta copying

Can help me out on how rsync is able to do this?
Or any idea which tool is able to do this?
Update1
I have tried
$ cp -Ra /src/ /dst/
$ du -sh /src
562M    /src
$ du -sh /src
48G     /dst

$ rsync -az --info=progress2 --hard-links /src/ /dst/
$ du -sh /src
562M    /src
$ du -sh /src
48G     /dst

I did a df -h and verified that my remote samba indeed decreased by 48G(!)
The only method I have so far is tar -cf src.tar /src, which turns /src into a much more reasonable 880M tar file. However, I prefer to have the files as-is for easier browsing and recovery.
Update2
I decide to start simple and connected my EXT4 to the same machine as the ZFS and rsync
# rsync -az --info=progress2 --hard-links /src/ /dst/
...
dst# du -sh
2.2G   .
dst# du -shl
9.2G    .
dst# cd /src
src# du -sh
1.9G    .
src# du -shl
8.2G    .

The storage discrepancy used is much smaller now, but why isn't it the same? Because of the filesystem? Or something about the rsync command?

The regular -H, --hard-links option will detect hardlinked files and replicate the links on the destination, which it does by comparing the inode numbers of all the 'source' files.
(Most copy tools, such as tar/cpio or even cp -a, are able to do the same.)
Delta copying is not very useful for local disk mounts – calculating the delta between 'old' and 'new' files requires reading them in full, and if you're going to read the entire 'old' file in full anyway, then you might as well write it straight to the destination. For that reason rsync only uses delta transfers when copying over network, but you can use --no-W, --no-whole-file to force enable delta mode (you might also want to use --inplace together with that).

thanks, let me try it out in a bit, /dst is actually a mounted remote

In src, du -shl for logical: 8.2G and du -sh for actual: 1.9G, but dst is a whopping 120G hmm...

What kind of network filesystem is it mounted as? Does it support hardlinks at all? In this situation it would make a lot more sense to run rsync over the network (so that the rsync sender could talk to a remote rsync receiver and then take advantage of delta transfer... though I don't think it has much support for delta copy).

src is zfs, dst is ext4.. but my bigger concern is why it became 120G from 1.9G

see my updated OP for more findings

"dst is ext4" is not enough – you said it's a network mount, so the network filesystem must also support everything that's needed. Your edit says that it's a Samba share; which SMB version does it use and does it support SMBv3.1.1 POSIX Extensions (or the old SMBv1 CIFS UNIX Extensions)? Without those, the client might be unable to create hardlinks no matter what kind of disk filesystem is underneath...

pvesm add cifs router --server 1.1.1.1 --share dst --smbversion 2.0 --content backup, I used this. I have 3.11, let me test it again

That sounds like a proxmox command on the client side? What OS is the SMB server running? The suggestion to use rsync-over-ssh (i.e. rsync /src user@host:/dst) still remains; it would be both vastly more efficient and probably a bit more reliable than rsync-over-network-share.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I made an update2 in the OP thanks
